# Is there a list of all included Python packages for any given Blender version?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I need a list of all the included Python packages like os, sys, requests, etc for Blender 3.2.2 (or any version for that matter).

I've tried looking in the API documentation but couldn't find any such list, it only specifies packages related to the the BPY library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual I find the answer 30 minutes after posting. Due to the limitation of Blender's python console on both Windows and Mac not being able to actual write out commands, you have to use the `help()` function in Python.

To print out all Python modules, including all BPY modules:

```
# script.py run in Blender
help('modules')
```

Result:

```
bone_selection_sets locale              real_snow
Cython              bpy                 logging             render_copy_settings
Test_Library        bpy_extras          lzma                render_freestyle_svg
__future__          bpy_restrict_state  magic_uv            render_povray
_abc                bpy_types           mailbox             render_ui_animation_render
_aix_support        btrace              mailcap             reprlib
_ast                builtins            main                requests
_asyncio            bz2                 manta               rigify
_bisect             cProfile            marshal             rlcompleter
_blake2             calendar            materials_library_vx rna_info
_bootsubprocess     camera_turnaround   materials_utils     rna_keymap_ui
_bpy_path           certifi             math                rna_manual_reference
_bz2                cgi                 mathutils           rna_prop_ui
_codecs             cgitb               measureit           rna_xml
_codecs_cn          charset_normalizer  mesh_auto_mirror    runpy
_codecs_hk          chunk               mesh_bsurfaces      sched
_codecs_iso2022     cmath               mesh_f2             secrets
_codecs_jp          cmd                 mesh_inset          select
_codecs_kr          code                mesh_looptools      selectors
_codecs_tw          codecs              mesh_snap_utilities_line setuptools
_collections        codeop              mesh_tiny_cad       shelve
_collections_abc    collections         mesh_tissue         shlex
_compat_pickle      colorsys            mesh_tools          shutil
_compression        compileall          mimetypes           signal
_contextvars        concurrent          mmap                site
_csv                configparser        modulefinder        smtpd
_ctypes             console             msilib              smtplib
_cycles             console_python      msvcrt              sndhdr
_datetime           console_shell       multiprocessing     socket
_decimal            contextlib          netrc               socketserver
_distutils_hack     contextvars         nntplib             space_clip
_elementtree        copy                node_arrange        space_clip_editor_refine_solution
_functools          copy_global_transform node_presets        space_console
_hashlib            copyreg             node_wrangler       space_dopesheet
_heapq              crypt               nodeitems_builtins  space_filebrowser
_imp                csv                 nodeitems_utils     space_graph
_io                 ctypes              nt                  space_image
_json               currency_converter  ntpath              space_info
_locale             curses              nturl2path          space_nla
_lsprof             curve_assign_shapekey numbers             space_node
_lzma               curve_simplify      numpy               space_outliner
_markupbase         curve_tools         object_boolean_tools space_properties
_md5                cycles              object_carver       space_sequencer
_msi                cython              object_collection_manager space_spreadsheet
_multibytecodec     dataclasses         object_color_rules  space_statusbar
_multiprocessing    datetime            object_edit_linked  space_text
_opcode             dbm                 object_fracture_cell space_time
_operator           decimal             object_print3d_utils space_toolsystem_common
_osx_support        depsgraph_debug     object_scatter      space_toolsystem_toolbar
_overlapped         development_edit_operator object_skinify      space_topbar
_pickle             development_icon_get opcode              space_userpref
_py_abc             development_iskeyfree operator            space_view3d
_pydecimal          difflib             optparse            space_view3d_3d_navigation
_pyio               dis                 os                  space_view3d_align_tools
_queue              distutils           paint_palette       space_view3d_brush_menus
_random             doctest             parameter_editor    space_view3d_copy_attributes
_sha1               email               pathlib             space_view3d_math_vis
_sha256             encodings           pdb                 space_view3d_modifier_tools
_sha3               ensurepip           pickle              space_view3d_pie_menus
_sha512             enum                pickletools         space_view3d_spacebar_menu
_signal             errno               pip                 space_view3d_stored_views
_sitebuiltins       faulthandler        pipes               space_view3d_toolbar
_socket             filecmp             pkg_resources       sqlite3
_sqlite3            fileinput           pkgutil             sre_compile
_sre                fnmatch             platform            sre_constants
_ssl                fractions           plistlib            sre_parse
_stat               freestyle           poplib              ssl
_statistics         ftplib              pose_library        stat
_string             functools           posixpath           statistics
_strptime           gc                  power_sequencer     string
_struct             genericpath         pprint              stringprep
_symtable           getopt              precision_drawing_tools struct
_thread             getpass             profile             subprocess
_threading_local    gettext             properties_animviz  sun_position
_tracemalloc        glob                properties_collection sunau
_uuid               gpu                 properties_constraint symtable
_warnings           gpu_extras          properties_data_armature sys
_weakref            graphlib            properties_data_bone sys_info
_weakrefset         graphviz_export     properties_data_camera sysconfig
_winapi             greasepencil_tools  properties_data_curve system_blend_info
_xxsubinterpreters  gzip                properties_data_curves system_demo_mode
_zoneinfo           hashlib             properties_data_empty system_property_chart
abc                 heapq               properties_data_gpencil tabnanny
add_camera_rigs     hmac                properties_data_lattice tarfile
add_curve_extra_objects html                properties_data_light telnetlib
add_curve_ivygen    http                properties_data_lightprobe tempfile
add_curve_sapling   idna                properties_data_mesh textwrap
add_mesh_BoltFactory idprop              properties_data_metaball this
add_mesh_discombobulator imaplib             properties_data_modifier threading
add_mesh_extra_objects imbuf               properties_data_pointcloud time
add_mesh_geodesic_domes imghdr              properties_data_shaderfx timeit
addon_utils         imp                 properties_data_speaker token
aifc                import_ase          properties_data_volume tokenize
amaranth            import_krita        properties_freestyle toml
animation_add_corrective_shape_key importlib           properties_grease_pencil_common trace
animation_animall   inspect             properties_mask_common traceback
animsys_refactor    io                  properties_material tracemalloc
ant_landscape       io_anim_bvh         properties_material_gpencil tty
antigravity         io_anim_camera      properties_object   types
archimesh           io_anim_nuke_chan   properties_output   typing
argparse            io_coat3D           properties_paint_common ui_translate
array               io_curve_svg        properties_particle unicodedata
ast                 io_export_dxf       properties_physics_cloth unittest
asynchat            io_export_paper_model properties_physics_common urllib
asyncio             io_export_pc2       properties_physics_dynamicpaint urllib3
asyncore            io_import_BrushSet  properties_physics_field utils
atexit              io_import_dxf       properties_physics_fluid uu
aud                 io_import_images_as_planes properties_physics_rigidbody uuid
audioop             io_import_palette   properties_physics_rigidbody_constraint venv
autopep8            io_mesh_atomic      properties_physics_softbody viewport_vr_preview
base64              io_mesh_ply         properties_render   warnings
bdb                 io_mesh_stl         properties_scene    wave
bgl                 io_mesh_uv_layout   properties_texture  weakref
binascii            io_scene_fbx        properties_view_layer webbrowser
binhex              io_scene_gltf2      properties_workspace winreg
bisect              io_scene_obj        properties_world    winsound
bl_app_override     io_scene_x3d        pstats              wsgiref
bl_app_template_utils io_shape_mdd        pty                 xdrlib
bl_i18n_utils       io_u_vertex_m       py_compile          xml
bl_keymap_utils     ipaddress           pyclbr              xmlrpc
bl_math             itertools           pycodestyle         xxsubtype
bl_operators        json                pydoc               zipapp
bl_rna_utils        keyingsets_builtins pydoc_data          zipfile
bl_ui               keyingsets_utils    pyexpat             zipimport
bl_ui_utils         keyword             pyximport           zlib
blend_render_info   lib2to3             queue               zoneinfo
blender_id          lighting_dynamic_sky quopri              zstandard
blf                 lighting_tri_lights random
```

Add-ons like Node Wrangler are included in this list as well, regardless if they are enabled or not.

Comment: modules that were manually installed with `pip install <package-name>` will also be included